# Take a range as an argument

Tags: c++

Many of the STL algorithms take a range and an argument. I am interested in seeing what it would take to take a range in my constructor.

Suppose I am making a Matrix class. What would the constructor look like?
I believe the forward iterator is the most generic.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Matrix
{
private:

    const size_t                m_order;
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> m_data;

public:

    Matrix(const size_t order, forward_iterator_tag begin, forward_iterator_tag end)
        :
        m_order(order)
      , m_data (order, std::vector<T>(order))
    {
        if (std::distance(begin, end) != order * order)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("invalid params");
        }

        for (size_t currentRow = 0; currentRow < m_order; ++currentRow)
        {
            for (size_t currentColumn = 0; currentColumn < m_order; ++currentColumn)
            {
                m_data[row].push_back(*begin);

                if (++begin == end)
                {
                    throw std::runtime_error("invalid params");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    T GetElement(size_t row, size_t column) const
    {
        if (row > order || column > order)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("invalid params");
        }

        return m_data[row][column];
    }
};


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Finds all permutations of the distinct numbers that make up a matrix of order n, from 1 to n^2
std::vector<std::vector<size_t>> GetAllPermutations(size_t order)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<size_t>> result;

    // It is important than we have these sorted least to greatest to start, in order to use the next_permutation algorithm
    std::vector<size_t> elements;
    for(size_t currentNumber = 1; currentNumber <= order * order; ++currentNumber)
    {
        elements.push_back(currentNumber);
    }

    do
    {
        // Store the current permutation
        result.push_back(elements);

    } while (std::next_permutation(elements.begin(), elements.end()));

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    const size_t order = 3;
    std::vector<std::vector<size_t>> permutations = GetAllPermutations(order);

    Matrix<size_t> matrix(order, permutations.begin(), permutations.end());

    return 0;
}
```

But the iterator is not the right type evidently. What do I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring your constructor's iterator parameters to be instances of `std::forward_iterator_tag`, which is an [iterator tag](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_tags), not an actual iterator.

Iterator tags are used for restricting template specializations to specific types of iterators.

For example, say an algorithm requires random-access iterators. It can produce a compiler error if non random-access iterators are passed to it.

Or, multiple overloads of a given algorithm can use iterator tags to restrict the type of iterators they accept, so they can use different logic/optimizations when passed different types of iterators.

In your case, to do what you want, you need to change your constructor to have a template parameter for the iterator type (just like STL algorithms do):

```
template<class InputIt>
Matrix(const size_t order, InputIt first, InputIt last)
```

Now, you can pass in whatever type of iterator you want (as long as dereferencing an iterator yields a value that is compatible with your `Matrix` class's `T` template parameter, since that is how your constructor body is using the iterator values).

Or, if you want to make sure that only iterators that are forward input iterators are passed in, and not any other types of iterators, you can do something more like this:

```
private:
    template<class InputIt>
    Matrix(const size_t order, InputIt first, InputIt last, std::forward_iterator_tag)
    {
        // initialization here ...
    }

public:
    template<class InputIt>
    Matrix(const size_t order, InputIt first, InputIt last)
        : Matrix(order, first, last, typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::iterator_category())
    {
    }
```

The code will compile only if `InputIt` is an iterator type whose `std::iterator_traits` specialization provides an `iterator_category` that is `std::forward_iterator_tag` or a descendant.

This approach is commonly known as [Tag Dispatching](https://www.boost.org/community/generic_programming.html#tag_dispatching).

Comment: What happened to type T for the type of data? There are two types that are needed.

Comment: `Matrix` only has 1 template parameter `T`. The approach I showed allows you to use whatever type of input iterators you want, as long as dereferencing a given iterator yields a value that is a `T`, or is implicitly convertible to a `T`

Comment: I got it to compile successfully, but I really don't understand what I am doing with 'typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::iterator_category()'

Comment: You don't have to use that if you don't want to. It is just a way of ensuring that whatever iterator type you use for `InputIt` is actually a forward input iterator, and not a non-forward input iterator, or an output iterator.

Comment: I want to. I just need to understand how it works better. Perhaps I should Google more on templates and typename.

Comment: Did you read the article I linked to in my answer? Using this technique, the code will compile only if the type of iterators (`InputIt`) you pass in are actually forward input iterators. In other words, if `iterator_category()` returns `std::forward_iterator_tag` or a descendant.  Otherwise, the code will not compile, since `iterator_category()` would return a value that cannot be passed to the parameter that is expecting a `std::forward_iterator_tag`

Comment: Yea, and I can match the text you type up with thier example, but there really isn't much there on what 'typename' keyword means, or how it works, or how it is passed and matched up with the tag.

Comment: Every type of iterator requires a [`std::iterator_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) specialization (the STL handles this for standard iterators, you have to provide your own if you write your own iterators). `iterator_category` specifies a specific type of iterator tag. `typename` tells the compiler that `iterator_category` is a type resolved using a template parameter (passed to `std::iterator_traits`) that is dependent on another template (the one from `Matrix`). Calling `iterator_category()` creates an instance of whatever type `iterator_category` refers to

Answer (score 0):

`forward_iterator_tag` is a tag that [defines the category of an iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_tags). You won't be able to initialize an iterator from that parameter.

Iterators can be pointers, classes, integers - basically any object that satisfies the [iterator categories](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator#Iterator_categories). Clearly you can't anticipate what the type of iterator you will be passed in the general case, which is why it is common to have your functions deduce the iterators with templates.

```
template<class InputIt>
void foo(InputIt begin, InputIt end);
```

This way you don't need to know the type of the iterators and can treat all possible iterator types in a uniform way.

Answer (score 0):

You made your life hard by using vector of vectors.
You don't need that and it leads to memory fragmentation.

```
template<class T>
class Matrix
{
private:
    std::size_t m_order;
    std::vector<T> m_data;

public:
    template <class InputIterator>
    Matrix(std::size_t order, 
           InputIterator begin, InputIterator end)
    : m_order(order)
    {
        if (std::distance(begin, end) > order * order) {
            throw std::runtime_error("invalid params");
        }
        m_data.reserve(order * order);
        std::copy(begin, end, std::back_inserter(m_data));
        m_data.resize(order * order);
    }

    T GetElement(size_t row, size_t column) const
    {
        checkIndexes(row, column);
        return m_data[row + column * m_order];
    }

    void SetElement(size_t row, size_t column, T value)
    {
        checkIndexes(row, column);
        m_data[row + column * m_order] = value;
    }

private:
    void checkIndexes(size_t row, size_t column) const {
        if (row > order || column > order) {
            throw std::runtime_error("invalid params");
        }
    }
… … …
```